# Spring - wrong encoding POST request with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying build an app that takes a POST(with x-www-form-urlencoded header) with one parameter.
This is my POST method code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/translate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getTranslate(@RequestParam("text") String text) {
     //................      
}
```

When i do POST request by Postman with data "Let’s measure"(image below) in method getTranslate text value is "Letâs measure".
What am I doing wrong?

[image: Image Attachment]

Comment: If my answer help you to fix the issue then please accept the answer, that will help others to get the exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you have missed to add encoding in the header of your request- just add content-type & encoding and try:

```
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
```

[image: Postman screenshot]